# Using JavaScript to read html / body tag margin-top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to read "marginTop" style property from the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Chrome developer tools shows margin-top as set via in-HTML CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

However, when I try something like this:

```
console.debug(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.marginTop);
console.debug(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop);
```

I get empty strings in both cases.

jQuery's `offset()` function detects margins correctly. Unfortunately, I cannot use jQuery in this case, it has to be pure JavaScript.

I would appreciate if someone could provide some insight on how I can read top margin property off the html and body elements.

Comment: why are you unable to use jquery in this instance? You can always look into jquery method of geting margins. Somewhere in its system it grabs the properties

Comment: It's an addon library. I don't have any control over environments it will be used in. It does not rely on jQuery and it would be silly to add it to requirements just for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve it with:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    marginTop = style.getPropertyValue('margin-top');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3vwP/2/)

Answer (score 3):

The `document` already has knowledge about `body` element, so:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('margin-top');
```