# got (an empty string) when trying to get marginTop value in js

Tags: javascript

```
<style>
  body { margin: 10px }
</style>
<body>
  <script> 
    console.log(document.body.style.marginTop); 
  </script>
</body>
```

Question:

in firefox->console it shows : `(an empty string)`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).marginTop
```

`document.body.style` returns inline styles

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
style = window.getComputedStyle(e),
marginTop = style.getPropertyValue('margin-top');

console.log(marginTop);
```

Related question and answer, see here: [Using JavaScript to read html / body tag margin-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121477/using-javascript-to-read-html-body-tag-margin-top)