# document.body.style.marginTop returning blank string in JS

Tags: javascript, margin

It was my understanding that [some elem].style.maginTop would return a string with the element's top margin.

Instead, I'm always getting a blank string. I want to use this with the body, but I also tried on a div, and that didn't work either.

```js
console.log(document.body.style.marginTop); // logs ""
console.log(typeof(document.body.style.marginTop)); // logs "String"

var elem = document.getElementById("testDiv");
console.log(elem.style.marginTop); // logs ""
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:100px;
}
#testDiv {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
hi!

<div id="testDiv">test</div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Does anybody have a non-jQuery solution to this?

Comment: Just checking: Do you run your script before or after body?

Comment: @tcak I'm currently using codepen, which I _believe_ places the script after the body. Though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) only returns inline styles:

> The HTMLElement.style property returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that represents the **element's style attribute**.

To access the styles from stylesheets use [Window.getComputedStyle(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of **all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets** and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("testDiv");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);

//output
document.body.innerHTML = style.marginTop;
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:100px;
}
#testDiv {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
hi!

<div id="testDiv">test</div>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. :) Any idea why my original attempt wasn't working?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to get top margin.

```js
console.log(document.body.style.marginTop); // logs ""
console.log(typeof(document.body.style.marginTop)); // logs "String"

var elem = document.getElementById("testDiv");
//console.log(elem.style.marginTop); // logs ""
console.log(getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("margin-top"));
alert(getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("margin-top"));
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:100px;
}
#testDiv {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
hi!

<div id="testDiv">test</div>
```

Tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't know why, but I got it working by implicitly assigning the `margin-top` by JS first.</del> I know why my answer works (it's been over 2 years so I better know why). By setting the values of `div#test` and `body` to `50px` and
`100px` like this:

```
document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop = '50px';
document.body.style.marginTop = '100px';
```

I'm actually setting the CSS property/value of the elements inline:

```
<body style='margin-top: 100px'>
  <div id='testDiv' style='margin-top: 50px'>test</div>
</body>
```

Whenever the `.style` property is used, the CSS property/value that follows it is always inline. One important thing to remember about inline CSS styles is that they have a higher priority than the other 2 means of CSS Declaration: external stylesheets (ex. `<link href="file.css"...`) and inline stylesheet (ex. `<style>...</style>`). The only way to override an inline style is to use `!important` (unless of course the inline style has `!important` as well.)

So if the`.style` property is used to read a property/value of an element, it'll only return the inline style value if it actually exists which in OP's case it never did and in my case it did because I used `.style` to assign the property/values. While my solution is correct, the answers by [Nicolo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34472910/2813224) and [Mr. Karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34472822/2813224) are better since you'll get the values from all CSS stylesheets.

```js
document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop = '50px';
document.body.style.marginTop = '100px';
console.log(document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop);
console.log(document.body.style.marginTop);
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#testDiv {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
hi!

<div id="testDiv">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using core javascript, let you use js library jQuery. Then use this syntaxt to get its value.:

```
console.log($('body').css('margin-top'));
```

for pure javascript use this

```
var element = document.body,
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    margin_top = style.getPropertyValue('margin-top');
        console.log(margin_top);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAw53/726/

Comment: *"Does anybody have a non-jQuery solution to this?"*

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I tried it as well with the same result as you did. A quick google search turned up [Using JavaScript to read html / body tag margin-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121477/using-javascript-to-read-html-body-tag-margin-top) which uses style.getPropertyValue() to return the information you're looking for.