# Getting margin-top with obj.style.marginTop failed, but it worked if marginTop was set explicitly first

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Please review this question first:**

[document.body.style.marginTop returning blank string in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34472770/2813224)

There were a couple working solutions... then there was my working solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34473070/2813224

**Summary:**

Tried to get the `margin-top` value of a div by doing the following code as well as variations of the same:

```
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[ Attempt 1 ]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

alert(document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop);

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[ Attempt 2 ]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

var tDiv = document.getElementById('testDiv');
var tMgn = tDiv.style.marginTop;
alert(tMgn);

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[ Attempt 3 ]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

var tDiv = document.querySelector('testDiv');
alert(tDiv.style.marginTop);

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[ Attempt 4 ]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

function mTop() {
   var tDiv = document.getElementById('testDiv');
   var tMgn = tDiv.style.marginTop;
   alert(tMgn);
}
mTop();
```

The one thing these combinations had in common is `.style.marginTop`. The Op's question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34472822/2813224) shortly thereafter.

**My question is this:**

I don't know why, but I got it working by explicitly assigning the `margin-top` by JS first. I never had to set a style value first just to get a style value back, especially if it's already set by CSS. Why would something simple like:

```
alert(document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop);
```

not work, but this does:

```
document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop = "50px";
alert(document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop);
```

When CSS is already:

```
#testDiv { margin-top: 50px; }
```

?

**Snippet of my working answer:**

```js
document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop = '50px';
document.body.style.marginTop = '100px';
alert(document.getElementById("testDiv").style.marginTop);
alert(document.body.style.marginTop);
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#testDiv {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
hi!

<div id="testDiv">test</div>
```

Comment: Probably because `element.style` only returns ***inline*** styles. For styles set in external stylesheets you'd need `getComputedStyle` instead

Comment: Thanks for your input, @adeneo Ok I see, but how is it possible that `element.style` for a block element returns the correct value when the value is assigned assigned by `element.style` beforehand?

Comment: `element.style` sets the styles inline, and again fetching styles with `element.style` ***only*** gets inline styles.

Comment: So if I had a column of divs and I used `element.style` to set a margin of one of them, that div would become inline and disrupt layout? That's something to remember for sure, thanks @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the style that was computed, but not set through JavaScript, as `HTMLElement.style` can get only the inline styles.

The syntax is:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("testDiv");
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("margin-top");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. As I was asking adeneo, when I set the value to a block using `HTMLElement.style`, I got the correct value back using `HTMLElement.style`. How is that possible?

Comment: That simple? I think this set, get , and forget will save me a lot of headaches, thank you, sir.

Comment: and a very dot Xmas to you as well, sir.